# Spring Data JPA order with NullHandling (Postgres)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with NullHandling in Spring Data. I am trying to pass custom NullHandling to my findAll method of repository - something like below:

```
Page<Developer> developerPage = developerRepository.findAll(
            new PageRequest(0, 2, new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "user").nullsFirst()))
    );
```

However, I have option show-sql set to true and in logs I see that in query which is passed to the database there is nothing mention about null handling. I get wrong results (even more different results for Postgres and H2 but I understand it is the difference between default null handling for each database). Configuration for Postgres is:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=postgres

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

What is the problem here? Is custom null handling supported in Spring Data JPA?

Edit:

I found out that query order part for JPA is created in QueryUtils class in method toOrders(..). What is interesting - Sort implementation from spring data is mapped to Sort implementation of JPA where there is no support for null handling. There is also a jira issue that describes that it is not supported but it is from 2014: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-491

Comment: hi Adam, did you find anything? I have the same issue atm.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this property in app.yml
spring.jpa.hibernate.order_by.default_null_ordering: last